# add_external_rule - rules deleted when visiting permalinks page

Tags: plugins, permalinks, rewrite-rules

In my plugin, I have the following function hooked to `register_activation_hook`. The rules are added correctly.

```
public function add_rules(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( '(.+)\.([0-9\.\-\_]+)\.(js|css)$' , '$1.$3');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
    update_option($this->key.'-plugin-version', $this->version);
}
```

When I visit the Permalink settings page, the rule is deleted again. It is not added back when saving the Permalink settings.

This is due to the way in which the [Permalink page flushes all rules](https://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_Permalinks_Screen) when it is opened. (Not when the settings are saved.)

Is there a way to stop the custom rules from being deleted?

Comment: You need to also hook to [`generate_rewrite_rules`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/generate_rewrite_rules)

Comment: I have hooked that to a function which dumps `$wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules`. These rules contain my custom rules. But the htaccess file isn't updated with them. Hooking into the ìnit` action seems to fix the problem, but most references I've seen advise against this for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leave your activation function as it is, and create another for the rewrite rules hook:

```
function wpse_209303_rewrite_rules( $wp_rewrite ) {
    $wp_rewrite->add_external_rule( '(.+)\.([0-9\.\-\_]+)\.(js|css)$' , '$1.$3');
}

add_action( 'generate_rewrite_rules', 'wpse_209303_rewrite_rules' );
```

Comment: The rule is still deleted when accessing /wp-admin/options-permalink.php. It isn't added back when saving the Permalink options.

Comment: Lemme investigate

Comment: Just tested, works fine for me - I get `RewriteRule ^(.+)\.([0-9\.\-\_]+)\.(js|css)$ /$1.$3 [QSA,L]` in my `.htaccess`. Make sure you've got [debugging on](https://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), disable all other plugins, switch to a default theme. Is there anything in *your* plugin you think might be interfering?

Comment: It's the only active plugin in an otherwise fresh, empty installation. The rules are added on activating the plugin, and removed when deactivating. But when I call up the Permalink page (/wp-admin/options-permalink.php), the rule is deleted. Only deactivating and reactivating the plugin puts them back.

Comment: That's very, very odd - I just tested the above on a vanilla install and everything worked fine. Can you post more of your plugin code? (anything you think might be relevant)

Comment: Thank you so much for your support. See https://gist.github.com/mhmli/fc35735a6e5fa668c22a Addendum: this problem is now fixed, but the `register_deactivation_hook` now no longer removes the rule!

Comment: [Try this](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/877788c66464bc7110e7), any q's let me know

Comment: Much cleaner! Solves the problem of this topic, but the deactivation no longer removes the rule from the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: You marked this solved, is it now working? I just tested the gist and deactivation removes the rewrite rule for me.

Comment: No, the deactivation problem still exists.

Comment: I marked it solved as the original problem is solved :)

Comment: Did you test the plugin exactly as it is in the gist? Like I say, it works for me (both activation & deactivation)